# Excel macro from Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have a process consisting of 15 macros. Each of them has to be run separately after closing and reopening Excel, otherwise excel crushes. It seems to be inefficient, so I am thinking of creating a macro in MS WORD, which could open an Excel Workbook, call a macro in it, close the WB, and do it again with the next macro.

I tried this: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/177760/acc97-how-to-run-macros-in-other-office-programs

But it didn't help. Something is happening, but visually Excel doesn't open. If I try to open this WB - it will say it's opened, but I can't see it and it's definitely not faster.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may have Excel processe running - look at your window task manager- Why would you wanna run your macros from Word? - also you may wanna post your code here so we can help you fix the issue

Comment: Rather than trying to show you how to run Excel from Word, it would be better if we helped you work out why your code is crashing Excel when you run more than one subroutine.

Comment: The issue here is that your code is crashing Excel, not that your work around isn't working! You should fix the issue source rather than treating the symptoms. I'm flagging this as off topic because there is no specific issue mentioned with supporting code or examples.

Comment: If you want to see Excel whilst you're controlling it from Word, then set the Application.Visible property to True

Comment: Why not to use VBScript to automate Excel then? Anyway share the code you have the issues with first.

Comment: In an ideal world your 15 macros could run one after the other without interruption, delivering the final result when they are done. This ideal result will be a lot easier to achieve in Excel alone than asking Word for help. (Remember the many cooks and the broth.) In a step by step solution you should post your code for macros 1 and 2 and ask why Excel crashes. Or ask how to join them into one.

Comment: Guys, the problem is not in the code. Excel files that VBA operates with are massive (up to 200K rows with formulas) and code works perfectly if I run my process step by step every time shutting down Excel and launch it again after every step. I assume it's some how connected to memory. Even though I have Core I7 and 8RAM, if I don't shut down Excel between steps,I get message that "Excel ran out of resources". So my Idea is to make MS Word to close and reopen Excel, clearing the memory. It's worth mentioning that other computers in my office would result the same.